Why does "val = yield x" run on its own in a separate output cell with val as x?
This is the code i wrote:
def genFunc():
    while True:
        val = yield True
        print(val)

myGen = genFunc()
next(myGen)
next(myGen)
myGen.send("Sending a message!")
next(myGen)
next(myGen)

Running in it in a .py file gives returns this:
None
Sending a message!
None
None

Running it in a jupyter cell (or vscode python interactive environment) returns this as two separate output blocks :
None
Sending a message!
None
None

True

I don't have any reasonable explanation as to why this is happening

All the None values are coming from print(val) inside the function, and they appear because next(myGen) is equivalent to myGen.send(None), i.e. you're sending in null values which are captured into local variable val by the yield expression.
The first next call does not cause a print, because that "primes" the generator function advancing it to the first yield statement, which is why you see two None printed after the Sending a message! but only one before it.
The True is the yielded value, returned to the caller from the yield expression, and when you're running this in a script it goes nowhere. But when you're running interactively it gets captured by a sys.displayhook and printed.
